# CXF wsdl2java set wsdlLocation of multiple wsdl

Tags: wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I trying to generate classes through CXF wsdl2java of multiple wsdl files. But I can't set the wsdl location of these wsdl files in a relative path into project. I have seen a solution setting options of each wsdl like this:

```
<configuration> 
            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/FooService.wsdl</wsdl>
                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/FooService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
```

But I don't want to do this of each case. I have this in my code:

```
<configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${generated.dir}</sourceRoot>
                        <defaultOptions>
                            <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf/date-binding.xml
                                </bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                        </defaultOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                        <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.wsdl</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
```

How can I set wsdlLocation in all wsdl's without set each one?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

You must add a wsdlRoot section in your configuration. Furthermore you must add a include section with wildcards.

This is my plugin section

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</wsdlRoot>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```